# Change text value after item is selected in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `combobox` with value in and extra value in the brackets "()", I want to find out if there is a way, that when I select a value it only shows the first part of the string, not the whole selected value.

I just want the first part of the description to be shown in the `combobox` text.

[image: I just want the first part of the description to show]

Comment: Yes, you can use string functions or regular expressions. But it's better to add objects as items of ComboBox, then you can extract desired information from those objects (items).

Comment: @Reza Aghaei I agree you with using objects but that will not solve the problem. He want's to change the look from the selected value and he would still have this problem when using objects.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code to share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the desired value using [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).
If you want the first 3 characters you can do it like this:

```
string.Substring(0,3);
```

If you want to change the text of the item, after it is selected, you will have to use an event of the `ComboBox`:

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                string s = comboBox.GetItemText(this.comboBox.SelectedItem).Substring(0, 3);
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.comboBox1.Text = s; });
            }
        }
```

Comment: would i do the same thing if the conbox has a databind?\

Comment: Well yes, don't you just want the text to be changed, when an item is selected. Check my last update.